# How do I display an alert dialog on Android?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialog

I want to display a dialog/popup window with a message to the user that shows "Are you sure you want to delete this entry?" with one button that says 'Delete'. When `Delete` is touched, it should delete that entry, otherwise nothing.

I have written a click listener for those buttons, but how do I invoke a dialog or popup and its functionality?

Comment: Here you are : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Comment: Why don't you use Material Dialog library!?

Comment: For one, two, and three button alert examples, [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43513919/android-alert-dialog-with-one-two-and-three-buttons/43513920#43513920).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement a confirmation (yes/no) DialogPreference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127407/how-to-implement-a-confirmation-yes-no-dialogpreference)

Answer (score 1973):

You could use an `AlertDialog` for this and construct one using its `Builder` class. The example below uses the default constructor that only takes in a `Context` since the dialog will inherit the proper theme from the Context you pass in, but there's also a constructor that allows you to specify a specific theme resource as the second parameter if you desire to do so.

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
    .setTitle("Delete entry")
    .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this entry?")

    // Specifying a listener allows you to take an action before dismissing the dialog.
    // The dialog is automatically dismissed when a dialog button is clicked.
    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
            // Continue with delete operation
        }
     })

    // A null listener allows the button to dismiss the dialog and take no further action.
    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null)
    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
    .show();
```

Comment: shouldn't the `AlertDialog.Builder(this)` be replaced by `AlertDialog.Builder(className.this)` ?

Comment: not necessarily. it is needed if you build alert dialog from some Listener.

Comment: Keep in mind AlertDialog.Builder cannot be dismissed via dismiss() method. You can use alternatively AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create(); and you will be able to call dismiss() on it normally.

Comment: Didn't work on drawer item selection, but this one did: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26097588/1953178

Comment: Not true @Fustigador

Comment: in my activity am getting api data with products in one array and cattegories in  another array first ineed to set all products to recycelrview and click categories optionsmenu icon display popup/dialog with categories data already getting if user select category onceagain getback clicked item and call api and update recycelerview with based on selected category data please help me

Comment: @Fustigador in `onClick()`, `DialogInterface dialog` can be used as `dialog.dismiss()` to dismiss a dialog.

Comment: @DavidBuilder: Is this example using DialogFragment or directly using AlertDialog? I thought the direct use was deprecated.

Comment: @AmroShafie Is no code do this(dismiss alert dialog) for me?

Comment: Best to use Mainactivity.this  with new AlertDialog.Builder.

Answer (score 396):

Try this code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
builder1.setMessage("Write your message here.");
builder1.setCancelable(true);

builder1.setPositiveButton(
    "Yes",
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

builder1.setNegativeButton(
    "No",
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
alert11.show();
```

Comment: +1. This is a much better way to do it. @Mahesh has created an instance of the dialog and therefore it's accessible to `cancel()` and so forth.

Comment: where should you put this in your code to create the builder exactly? I know when you use it.

Comment: @MicroR Anywhere where it will be ran when you want an alert. You could put it inside a method that a button's onClick attribute points to for example.

Comment: Is `builder1.create()` necessary because it seems to work fine when you call `builder1.show()` directly?

Comment: @razzak yes its necessary because its provide us dialog instance. we  can  use dialog instance to access dialog specific method

Comment: I'm trying this method but the alert window pops up and disappears immediately, without letting me time to read it. I obviously don't have time to click on the buttons to dismiss it either. Any idea why?

Comment: Nevermind, I found the reason why, I was firing a new Intent and it was not waiting for my alert windows to pop, as I could find here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6336930/android-dialog-disappears-on-its-own

Comment: This code is working great. However I want to put all my alerts in a separate Java class. The method will be static so I can call `Alerts.error1()`. However I'm not sure how to transfer over the `context` as `this` doesn't work when it's in another class. I tried `Alerts.error1(view)` but that's throwing me a `Error:(13, 63) error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context`.

Comment: @Regis you need pass context as parameter to method error , like Alert.error(context);

Answer (score 109):

The code which David Hedlund has posted gave me the error:

> Unable to add window — token null is not valid

If you are getting the same error use the below code. It works!!

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        if (!isFinishing()){
            new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this)
              .setTitle("Your Alert")
              .setMessage("Your Message")
              .setCancelable(false)
              .setPositiveButton("ok", new OnClickListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                      // Whatever...
                  }
              }).show();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: We don't need to use both `create()` and `show()`, as `show()` already creates the dialog with the content described. According to the documentation, `create()` _Creates a AlertDialog with the arguments supplied to this builder. It does not Dialog.show() the dialog. This allows the user to do any extra processing before displaying the dialog. **Use show() if you don't have any other processing to do and want this to be created and displayed.**_ Therefore it is only useful to use `create()` if you are planning on showing the dialog later, and you are loading its contents in advance.

Comment: Changed param from `getApplicationContext()` to `MyActivity.this` and started working.

Answer (score 96):

Use **AlertDialog.Builder** :

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
//set icon 
 .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
//set title
.setTitle("Are you sure to Exit")
//set message
.setMessage("Exiting will call finish() method")
//set positive button
.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
   //set what would happen when positive button is clicked    
        finish();
    }
})
//set negative button
.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
   //set what should happen when negative button is clicked
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Nothing Happened",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
})
.show();
```

You will get the following output.

[image: android alert dialog]

To view alert dialog tutorial use the link below.

[Android Alert Dialog Tutorial](http://larntech.net/android-display-alert-dialog/)

Comment: what if the xml is from our creation?

Answer (score 78):

Just a simple one! Create a dialog method, something like this anywhere in your Java class:

```
public void openDialog() {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context); // Context, this, etc.
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_demo);
    dialog.setTitle(R.string.dialog_title);
    dialog.show();
}
```

Now create Layout XML `dialog_demo.xml` and create your UI/design. Here is a sample one I created for demo purposes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_info"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/dialog_text"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/dialog_info">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dialog_cancel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:background="@color/dialog_cancel_bgcolor"
            android:text="Cancel"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dialog_ok"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:background="@color/dialog_ok_bgcolor"
            android:text="Agree"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now you can call `openDialog()` from anywhere you like :) Here is the screenshot of above code.

[image]

Note that text and color are used from `strings.xml` and `colors.xml`. You can define your own.

Comment: The Dialog class is the base class for dialogs, but you should **avoid** instantiating Dialog directly. Instead, use one of the following subclasses:

`AlertDialog, DatePickerDialog or TimePickerDialog`
(from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html )

Comment: "Cancel" and "Agree" are not clickable here.

Comment: you need to define your own onClick listener from there on...

Answer (score 56):

Nowadays it's better to use DialogFragment instead of direct AlertDialog creation.

- How? See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21032871/1390874
- Why? See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13765411/1390874

Comment: Plus I got so many troubles trying to get rid of a weird system AlertDialog background when inflating it with my custom contents view.

Answer (score 45):

You can use this code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(
    AlertDialogActivity.this);

// Setting Dialog Title
alertDialog2.setTitle("Confirm Delete...");

// Setting Dialog Message
alertDialog2.setMessage("Are you sure you want delete this file?");

// Setting Icon to Dialog
alertDialog2.setIcon(R.drawable.delete);

// Setting Positive "Yes" Btn
alertDialog2.setPositiveButton("YES",
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // Write your code here to execute after dialog
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                           "You clicked on YES", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    });

// Setting Negative "NO" Btn
alertDialog2.setNegativeButton("NO",
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // Write your code here to execute after dialog
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                           "You clicked on NO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

// Showing Alert Dialog
alertDialog2.show();
```

Comment: dialog.cancel(); shouldn't be called in second listener

Answer (score 42):

for me

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("Closing application")
    .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

          }
     }).setNegativeButton("No", null).show();
```

Answer (score 35):

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
    .setTitle("title")
    .setMessage("message")
    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
    .show();
```

Answer (score 34):

```
// Dialog box

public void dialogBox() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Click on Image for tag");
    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
        }
    });

    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("cancel",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

        }
    });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Yout code is incorrect, you need to change setPositiveButton("cancel" to setNegativeButton("cancel"

Comment: Thanks, Its happened by mistake... Actually I want to check that anyone can check the posted code deeply or not. And you are the one...thanks again..

Answer (score 25):

This is a basic sample of how to create an [Alert Dialog](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) :

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
dialog.setCancelable(false);
dialog.setTitle("Dialog on Android");
dialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this entry?" );
dialog.setPositiveButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        //Action for "Delete".
    }
})
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel ", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //Action for "Cancel".
            }
        });

final AlertDialog alert = dialog.create();
alert.show();
```

[image]

Answer (score 21):

With the **Material Components Library** you can just use the  **`MaterialAlertDialogBuilder`**

```
   MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(context)
        .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this entry?")
        .setPositiveButton("Delete") { dialog, which ->
            // Respond to positive button press
        }
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel") { dialog, which ->
            // Respond to positive button press
        }   
        .show()
```

[image]

With **Compose** `1.0.x` you can use:

```
val openDialog = remember { mutableStateOf(true) }

if (openDialog.value) {
    AlertDialog(
        onDismissRequest = {
            // Dismiss the dialog when the user clicks outside the dialog or on the back
            // button. If you want to disable that functionality, simply use an empty
            // onCloseRequest.
            openDialog.value = false
        },
        title = null,
        text = {
            Text(
                "Are you sure you want to delete this entry?"
            )
        },
        confirmButton = {
            TextButton(
                onClick = {
                    openDialog.value = false
                }
            ) {
                Text("Delete")
            }
        },
        dismissButton = {
            TextButton(
                onClick = {
                    openDialog.value = false
                }
            ) {
                Text("Cancel")
            }
        }
    )
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 20):

```
showDialog(MainActivity.this, "title", "message", "OK", "Cancel", {...}, {...});
```

## Kotlin

```
fun showDialog(context: Context, title: String, msg: String,
               positiveBtnText: String, negativeBtnText: String?,
               positiveBtnClickListener: DialogInterface.OnClickListener,
               negativeBtnClickListener: DialogInterface.OnClickListener?): AlertDialog {
    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
            .setTitle(title)
            .setMessage(msg)
            .setCancelable(true)
            .setPositiveButton(positiveBtnText, positiveBtnClickListener)
    if (negativeBtnText != null)
        builder.setNegativeButton(negativeBtnText, negativeBtnClickListener)
    val alert = builder.create()
    alert.show()
    return alert
}
```

## Java

```
public static AlertDialog showDialog(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull String title, @NonNull String msg,
                                     @NonNull String positiveBtnText, @Nullable String negativeBtnText,
                                     @NonNull DialogInterface.OnClickListener positiveBtnClickListener,
                                     @Nullable DialogInterface.OnClickListener negativeBtnClickListener) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
            .setTitle(title)
            .setMessage(msg)
            .setCancelable(true)
            .setPositiveButton(positiveBtnText, positiveBtnClickListener);
    if (negativeBtnText != null)
        builder.setNegativeButton(negativeBtnText, negativeBtnClickListener);
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
    return alert;
}
```

Answer (score 17):

This is definitely help for you. Try this code: On click of a button, you can put one, two or three buttons with an alert dialog...

```
SingleButtton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // Creating alert Dialog with one Button

        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(AlertDialogActivity.this).create();

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("Alert Dialog");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("Welcome to Android Application");

        // Setting Icon to Dialog
        alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.tick);

        // Setting OK Button
        alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which)
            {
                // Write your code here to execute after dialog    closed
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You clicked on OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }
});

btnAlertTwoBtns.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // Creating alert Dialog with two Buttons

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(AlertDialogActivity.this);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("Confirm Delete...");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want delete this?");

        // Setting Icon to Dialog
        alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.delete);

        // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                        // Write your code here to execute after dialog
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on YES", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

        // Setting Negative "NO" Button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,    int which) {
                        // Write your code here to execute after dialog
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on NO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }
});

btnAlertThreeBtns.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // Creating alert Dialog with three Buttons

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                AlertDialogActivity.this);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("Save File...");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("Do you want to save this file?");

        // Setting Icon to Dialog
        alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.save);

        // Setting Positive Yes Button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                        int which) {
                    // User pressed Cancel button. Write Logic Here
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "You clicked on YES",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

        // Setting Negative No Button... Neutral means in between yes and cancel button
        alertDialog.setNeutralButton("NO",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                        int which) {
                    // User pressed No button. Write Logic Here
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "You clicked on NO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            });

        // Setting Positive "Cancel" Button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                        int which) {
                    // User pressed Cancel button. Write Logic Here
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "You clicked on Cancel",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 15):

I have created a dialog for asking a Person whether he wants to call a Person or not.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Firstclass extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.first);

        ImageView imageViewCall = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ring_mig);

        imageViewCall.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                try
                {
                    showDialog("0728570527");
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void showDialog(final String phone) throws Exception
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Firstclass.this);

        builder.setMessage("Ring: " + phone);

        builder.setPositiveButton("Ring", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);// (Intent.ACTION_CALL);

                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phone));

                startActivity(callIntent);

                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("Avbryt", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        builder.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

you can try this....

```
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
dialog.setCancelable(false);
dialog.setTitle("Dialog on Android");
dialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this entry?" );
dialog.setPositiveButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        //Action for "Delete".
    }
})
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel ", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //Action for "Cancel".
            }
        });

final AlertDialog alert = dialog.create();
alert.show();
```

[For more info,check this link...](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html)

Answer (score 13):

Try this code

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

    // set title
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("AlertDialog Title");

    // set dialog message
    alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("Some Alert Dialog message.")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            Toast.makeText(this, "OK button click ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("CANCEL",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                           Toast.makeText(this, "CANCEL button click ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

    // create alert dialog
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

    // show it
    alertDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 11):

You can create the dialog box using `AlertDialog.Builder`

**Try this:**

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this entry?");

        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes, please", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //perform any action
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Yes clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //perform any action
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        //creating alert dialog
        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
```

To change the color of the positive & negative buttons of Alert dialog you can write the below two lines after `alertDialog.show();`

```
alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

I was using this `AlertDialog` in button `onClick` method:

```
button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater layoutInflaterAndroid = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View view = layoutInflaterAndroid.inflate(R.layout.cancel_dialog, null);
    builder.setView(view);
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    final AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();

    view.findViewById(R.id.yesButton).setOnClickListener(v -> onBackPressed());
    view.findViewById(R.id.nobutton).setOnClickListener(v -> alertDialog.dismiss());
});
```

**dialog.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textmain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="@string/warning"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textpart2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:lines="2"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:text="@string/dialog_cancel"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textmain" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/yesButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:background="#87cefa"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="@string/yes"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textpart2" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nobutton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
    android:background="#87cefa"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="@string/no"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/yesButton" />


<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/nobutton" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Please update the provided code with an explanation of what it exactly does.

Answer (score 8):

Just be careful when you want to dismiss the dialog - use `dialog.dismiss()`. In my first attempt I used `dismissDialog(0)` (which I probably copied from some place) which *sometimes* works. Using the object the system supplies sounds like a safer choice.

Answer (score 8):

```
   new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext()).setMessage("msg to display!").show();
```

Comment: Explanation Please

Comment: No explanation, please.  This answer is perfect, and any attempt at adding words to appease the "Explanation please" bots would make it worse.

Answer (score 7):

I'd like to add on David Hedlund great answer by sharing a more dynamic method than what he posted so it can be used when you do have a negative action to perform and when you don't, i hope it helps.

```
private void showAlertDialog(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull String alertDialogTitle, @NonNull String alertDialogMessage, @NonNull String positiveButtonText, @Nullable String negativeButtonText, @NonNull final int positiveAction, @Nullable final Integer negativeAction, @NonNull boolean hasNegativeAction)
{
    AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, android.R.style.Theme_Material_Dialog_Alert);
    } else {
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    }
    builder.setTitle(alertDialogTitle)
            .setMessage(alertDialogMessage)
            .setPositiveButton(positiveButtonText, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    switch (positiveAction)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            //TODO:Do your positive action here 
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });
            if(hasNegativeAction || negativeAction!=null || negativeButtonText!=null)
            {
            builder.setNegativeButton(negativeButtonText, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    switch (negativeAction)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            //TODO:Do your negative action here
                            break;
                        //TODO: add cases when needed
                    }
                }
            });
            }
            builder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
            builder.show();
}
```

Answer (score 7):

**Simplest Solution For Kotln Developers**

```
val alertDialogBuilder: AlertDialog.Builder = AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(msg)
    alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(true)

    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton(
        getString(android.R.string.ok)
    ) { dialog, _ ->
        dialog.cancel()
    }

    val alertDialog: AlertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create()
    alertDialog.show()
```

Answer (score 7):

```
     new AlertDialog.Builder(loginregister.this)
            .setTitle("messege")
            .setPositiveButton("ok", null)
            .setMessage( "user name : " + username + "/n" +
                            "password :" + password + "/n"  )
    .show();
```

Answer (score 5):

```
public void showSimpleDialog(View view) {
    // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setTitle("AlertDialog Title");
    builder.setMessage("Simple Dialog Message");
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK!!!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            //
        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("Cancel ", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
    });

    // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
    builder.create().show();
}
```

Also check out my blog on Dialogs in Android, you will find all the details here: http://www.fahmapps.com/2016/09/26/dialogs-in-android-part1/.

Answer (score 5):

This is done in kotlin

```
val builder: AlertDialog.Builder = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            AlertDialog.Builder(this, android.R.style.Theme_Material_Dialog_Alert)
        } else {
            AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        }
        builder.setTitle("Delete Alert!")
                .setMessage("Are you want to delete this entry?")
                .setPositiveButton("YES") { dialog, which ->

                }
                .setNegativeButton("NO") { dialog, which ->

                }
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                .show()
```

Answer (score 4):

you may try this way also, it will provide you material style dialogs

```
private void showDialog()
{
    String text2 = "<font color=#212121>Medi Notification</font>";//for custom title color

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle);
    builder.setTitle(Html.fromHtml(text2));

    String text3 = "<font color=#A4A4A4>You can complete your profile now or start using the app and come back later</font>";//for custom message
    builder.setMessage(Html.fromHtml(text3));

    builder.setPositiveButton("DELETE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
        {
            toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DELETE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            toast.show();              
        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
        {
            toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CANCEL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            toast.show();
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Alert dialog with edit text

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);//Context is activity context
final EditText input = new EditText(context);
builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.remove_item_dialog_title));
        builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.dialog_message_remove_item));
 builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.update_qty));
            builder.setMessage("");
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            input.setLayoutParams(lp);
            input.setHint(getString(R.string.enter_qty));
            input.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.textColor));
            input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
            input.setText("String in edit text you want");
            builder.setView(input);
   builder.setPositiveButton(getString(android.R.string.ok),
                (dialog, which) -> {

//Positive button click event
  });

 builder.setNegativeButton(getString(android.R.string.cancel),
                (dialog, which) -> {
//Negative button click event
                });
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 4):

Make this static method and use it where ever you want.

```
public static void showAlertDialog(Context context, String title, String message, String posBtnMsg, String negBtnMsg) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder.setTitle(title);
            builder.setMessage(message);
            builder.setPositiveButton(posBtnMsg, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton(negBtnMsg, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();

        }
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this for **Kotlin**

```
AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Title")
            .setPositiveButton("Yes"){ dialog, which ->

            }
            .setNegativeButton("No", null)
            .setMessage("Your given alert message...")
            .show()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("This is Title");
    builder.setMessage("This is message for Alert Dialog");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Positive Button", (dialog, which) -> onBackPressed());
    builder.setNegativeButton("Negative Button", (dialog, which) -> dialog.cancel());
    builder.show();
```

This is a way which alike to create the Alert dialog with some line of code.

Answer (score 2):

Code to delete an entry from the list

```
 /*--dialog for delete entry--*/
private void cancelBookingAlert() {
    AlertDialog dialog;
    final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this, R.style.AlertDialogCustom);
    alertDialog.setTitle("Delete Entry");
    alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this entry?");
    alertDialog.setCancelable(false);

    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
           //code to delete entry
        }
    });

    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    dialog = alertDialog.create();
    dialog.show();
}
```

**Call above method on delete button click**

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin Custom dialog:
In Case if you want to create custom dialog

```
Dialog(activity!!, R.style.LoadingIndicatorDialogStyle)
        .apply {
            // requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
            setCancelable(true)
            setContentView(R.layout.define_your_custom_view_id_here)

            //access your custom view buttons/editText like below.z
            val createBt = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.clipboard_create_project)
            val cancelBt = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.clipboard_cancel_project)
            val clipboard_et = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.clipboard_et)
            val manualOption =
                findViewById<TextView>(R.id.clipboard_manual_add_project_option)

            //if you want to perform any operation on the button do like this

            createBt.setOnClickListener {
                //handle your button click here
                val enteredData = clipboard_et.text.toString()
                if (enteredData.isEmpty()) {
                    Utils.toast("Enter project details")
                } else {
                    navigateToAddProject(enteredData, true)
                    dismiss()
                }
            }

            cancelBt.setOnClickListener {
                dismiss()
            }
            manualOption.setOnClickListener {
                navigateToAddProject("", false)
                dismiss()
            }
            show()
        }
```

Create LoadingIndicatorDialogStyle in style.xml

```
<style name="LoadingIndicatorDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/black_transperant</item>
<item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
<item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
<!--<item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/MaterialDialogSheetAnimation</item>-->
```

Answer (score 1):

With [Anko](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/wiki/Anko-Commons-%E2%80%93-Dialogs#alerts) (official library from developers of Kotlin), you can simple use

```
alert("Alert title").show()
```

or more complex one:

```
alert("Hi, I'm Roy", "Have you tried turning it off and on again?") {
    yesButton { toast("Oh…") }
    noButton {}
}.show()
```

To import Anko:

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko:0.10.8"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(HistoryActivity.this);
    final View vv = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_processing_tts, null);
    final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            HistoryActivity.this);
    alert.setTitle("Delete");
    alert.setView(vv);
    alert.setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    databaseHelperClass.deleteHistory(list.get(position).getID());
                    list.clear();
                    setAdapterForList();

                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

    final AlertDialog dialog = alert.create();
    dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Now with **Jetpack Compose** introduced in android , you can simply create alert dialog using below code

```
if (viewModel.shouldDialogOpen.value) {

        AlertDialog(onDismissRequest = { viewModel.shouldDialogOpen.value = false },
            title = { Text("Delete Entry?") },
            text = {
                Text("Are you sure you want to delete this entry?")
            },
            dismissButton = {
                Button(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), onClick = {
                    viewModel.shouldDialogOpen.value = false
                }) {
                    Text(text = "Cancel")
                }
            }, confirmButton = {
                Button(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), onClick = {
                    viewModel.shouldDialogOpen.value = false
                    viewModel.beginDelete(recipe)
                }) {
                    Text(text = "Okay")
                }
            })
    }
```

Here In `viewModel.shouldDialogOpen`, `shouldDialogOpen` is a mutablestate field inside viewmodel whose value we change when we need to show or dismiss dialog.

For more code samples for Jetpack Compose:- https://androidlearnersite.wordpress.com/2021/08/03/jetpack-compose-1-0-0-sample-codes/

Answer (score 0):

You can create Activity and extends AppCompatActivity. Then in the Manifest put next style:

```
<activity android:name=".YourCustomDialog"
            android:theme="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
</activity>
```

Inflate it by Buttons and TextViews

Then use this like a dialog.

For example, in the linearLayout I fill next parameters:

```
android:layout_width="300dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Answer (score 0):

In past few days my co-workers keep asking me about using `AlertDialog` in `Xamarin.Android` and almost all of them sent this question as the ref which they read before asking me (and didn't find the answer), so here is `Xamarin.Android` (`C#`) version:

```
var alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this) // this: Activity
    .SetTitle("Hello!")
    .SetMessage("Are you sure?")
    .SetPositiveButton("Ok", (sender, e) => { /* ok things */ })
    .SetNegativeButton("Cancel", (sender, e) => { /* cancel things */ })
    .Create();

alertDialog.Show();

// you can customize your AlertDialog, like so
var tvMessage = alertDialog.FindViewById<TextView>(Android.Resource.Id.Message);
tvMessage.TextSize = 13;
// ...
```