# Reset settings option in PreferenceScreen

Tags: android

I checked different options that are available in PreferenceScreen (eg. CheckBoxPreference, EditTextPreference, etc.) but non of them give me the possiblity to obtain a simple dialog with just 2 buttons. I would like to use it to implement a basic “Yes, reset my app” / “Cancel” features. How to make this preference option easily?

Comment: The Preference widgets are limited. You can use a ListPreference (with 2 item to simulate your 2 buttons) or try to build your own custom Preference, extending some existing one.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127407/how-to-implement-a-confirmation-yes-no-dialogpreference

Comment: Artoo Detoo, for me ListPreference with 2 items does not look good.  Madhur Ahuja I checked the link now but I don't know how to solve com.android.internal.R.attr.yesNoPreferenceStyle error in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its tricky check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14153316/1878151) answer. 
Well I've implemented EditText Preference which shows 2 buttons ok and cancel but in middle there is Edittext.

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I need! But I have one problem in adding the original soure code from the given link. In constructor I get the error in line with "com.android.internal.R.attr.yesNoPreferenceStyle". How can I fix it?

Comment: @Annabelle: gotcha it working fine now. I want you to create another pacakage name it "com.android.internal.preference". Create new class in it and paste that code inside it. Now just comment 2nd and 3rd YesNoPreference constructor.

Comment: I found a different solution: I added justa a Preference option, I implemented onPreferenceClick and in onClick I created new AlertDialog.Builder. It's not perfect ideal solution, but works.

Comment: Thats g8 alternative. Ahh just do it ur way its a bit simple.