# ADK - User prompt dialog is cancelled/bypassed almost instantly

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog, adk

I am attempting to prompt a user for input based on prior input.

Allow me to clarify and add some context:
This application is a dice-rolling simulator. The main activity displays the number of dice and number of sides on each die, which is changed by opening a sub-activity from the menu. This sub-activity is called for its result using `startActivityForResult()`, and consists entirely of a `RadioGroup` and two buttons - "Accept" and "Cancel" - and passes a `String` extra back to the main activity (in the format "XdN" - e.g. "1d20"), which the main activity then parses and uses to adjust the dice count and side count accordingly.

This system works exceptionally well for examples like "1d6", "1d10", and the like, and is **not** the problem - *as far as I know*.

Now, here's my problem:
I have a radio button that passes the `String` "Custom" (instead of an "XdN"-like `String`). When selected (and, finally, when "Accept" is clicked), my intention is for a dialog to open and prompt the user for custom count values - and this works, sort of. The dialog shows, and the layout is correct and looks like it should, but **the layout then disappears after a split-second and passes the current count values instead of the values that *would* have been entered by the user.** This also throws an error to LogCat (I'm using Eclipse and ADT) that says:

```
Application            Tag             Text
org.x3chaos.nicedice   WindowManager   Activity org.x3chaos.nicedice.DiceActivity
                                       has leaked window com.android.internal.pol
                                       icy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@44786f20 th
                                       at was originally added here
org.x3chaos.nicedice   WindowManager   android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity org.x3
                                       chaos.nicedice.DiceActivity has leaked win
                                       dow com.android.internal.policy.impl.Phone
                                       Window$DecorView@44786f20 that was origina
                                       ly added here
org.x3chaos.nicedice   WindowManager   at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.j
                                       ava:247)

[more if needed]
```

--

The `Button` *button_accept*'s `android:onClick` method follows:

```
public void accept(View view) {

    RadioGroup group = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.dice_radiogrp);
    RadioButton selected = (RadioButton) findViewById(group
            .getCheckedRadioButtonId());
    String tmpResult = selected.getText().toString();

    if (!tmpResult.matches("[0-9|xX](.*)[Dd][0-9](.*)")) {

        // Show dialog

        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View dialogView = li.inflate(R.layout.prompt_dice, null);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setView(dialogView);
        builder.setTitle("Custom Dice");
        builder.setCancelable(false);

        final EditText editCount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_promptDiceCount);
        final EditText editSides = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_promptDiceSides);

        builder.setPositiveButton("Accept", new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                boolean flag = false;
                String textCount, textSides;
                textCount = editCount.getText().toString();
                if (textCount.equals("")) {
                    textCount = "1";
                    flag = true;
                }
                textSides = editSides.getText().toString();
                if (textSides.equals("")) {
                    textSides = "20";
                    flag = true;
                }

                int count = Integer.parseInt(textCount);
                int sides = Integer.parseInt(textSides);

                if (count > 20)
                    count = 20;
                if (sides > 20)
                    sides = 20;

                String finRes = count + "d" + sides;

                setResultExtra(finRes);

                if (flag) {
                    String msg = "Invalid input: set dice to " + finRes;
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, msg,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                }

            }

        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
                exitActivity(false);
            }

        });

        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();

    } else {
        result = tmpResult;
    }

    exitActivity(true);

}
```

All other functions work, so I'm not sure why this isn't. I'm sure it's something that I'm messing up - seeing as this is my first app and I'm using some objects and methods that I've never touched before - so I really appreciate any help. :]

**EDIT:** After reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6336930/android-dialog-disappears-on-its-own), I'm starting to think that maybe it's an `Intent` that's not waiting for the dialog to finish. But this doesn't quite make sense, since the activity that calls the dialog is called for a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android dialogs are **asynchronous**. You cannot display it and expect that your code waits here. And what you do is `dialog.show()` and then instantly `exitActivity()` so it seems it works the way you made it.

**EDIT**

Quick fix for your code could probably be to replace this portion:

```
} else {
    result = tmpResult;
}

exitActivity(true);
```

with

```
} else {
    result = tmpResult;
    exitActivity(true);
}
```

becasue this `exitActivity()` is what causes you problems.

Comment: Right, right; I can see that. But how would I remedy the situation? That's what I'm asking. Would I have to switch out the dialog with another activity?

Comment: Yup, that was it. I had to do a bit more rearranging, but the basic premise worked. Thanks, mate. +1