# ASP.NET - C# alert for Android devices

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, alert

I have to display an alert on Android mobile phone. I'm working with asp.net (c#) and when I use:

```
protected void CheckNumber(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    if (Convert.ToInt64(TextBox.Text) <= 0)
    {
         Response.Write("<script>alert('The number must be positive')</script>");
         return;
    }
    ...
}
```

there is no message or screen which opens on top.

I have also tried this without any difference:

```
if (Convert.ToInt64(TextBox.Text) <= 0)
{
      MessageBox.Show("The number must be positive!");
      return;
}
...
```

How can I have a message and a confirm button on the mobile screen?

Comment: check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115758/how-to-display-alert-dialog-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use `Toasts` http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html ,

or use `AlertDialog` http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-alert/