# Language choose pop-up <Android>

Tags: android, popup

i want to have simple pop up after start of my app where users can choose from languages of the app (which should use different xmls)

after first chose it should not appear on next run of app and it should be changeable from settings button.

I am an Android dummy and realy need it, thanks much

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: i dont know hot to make any pop-up, after that i know that it should use sharedpreferences, which last time didnt work for me etc.. :D

Comment: Have you [searched](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115758/how-to-display-alert-dialog-in-android)? And, yes, sharedprefs. Give it a try and post what isn't working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use shared preference for this eg:-

```
private SharedPreferences mPreferences;
boolean firstTime = mPreferences.getBoolean("firstTime", true);
if (firstTime) { 
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPreferences.edit();
editor.putBoolean("firstTime", false);
editor.commit();
SelectLanguge();
}
```