# How to Dialog in a class which extens Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

In a class which extends fragment... I have to show dialog
I am using this code but my application stops can any one help me..

```
c = getActivity();
Dialog dia = new Dialog(c);
dia.setTitle("No Internet Access");
TextView tvw = (TextView) dia.findViewById(R.id.tv_test);
tvw.setText("connect to the internet");
dia.setContentView(tvw);
dia.show();
```

Comment: post your logcat error and give us some more information.

Comment: I got my error, I was passing wrong id to the TextView()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my error, I was passing wrong id to the TextView()

Answer (score 0):

You should use [DialogFragments](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html).

Check [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html) out.

If you don't want to go into DialogFragments, you can just build a simple dialog. For that check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2115770/562840) answer.