# Is it possible to create a custom Android dialog for Unity?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, unity-game-engine, dialog

I am trying to create a custom Dialog for Android for Unity. I know how to create custom Dialog in a pure Android App. Also, I can create DatePickerDialog and TimePickerDialog from Android to work in a Unity app.

If I try to do create a custom Dialog in Java (Android) and then connect the .jar with my Unity C# code, I get this in runtime:

> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class paths
>   12-01 01:33:14.658: E/AndroidRuntime(20499):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:698)
>   12-01 01:33:14.658: E/AndroidRuntime(20499):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
>   12-01 01:33:14.658: E/AndroidRuntime(20499):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
>   12-01 01:33:14.658: E/AndroidRuntime(20499):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
>   12-01 01:33:14.658: E/AndroidRuntime(20499):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:313)
>   12-01 01:33:14.658: E/AndroidRuntime(20499):    at android.app.Dialog.setContentView(Dialog.java:467)
>   12-01 01:33:14.658: E/AndroidRuntime(20499):    at com.test.CustomDialog.onCreate(CustomDialog.java:48)
>   12-01 01:33:14.658: E/AndroidRuntime(20499):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
>   12-01 01:33:14.658: E/AndroidRuntime(20499):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
>   12-01 01:33:14.658: E/AndroidRuntime(20499):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
>   12-01 01:33:14.658: E/AndroidRuntime(20499):    ... 11 more
>   12-01 01:33:14.658: E/AndroidRuntime(20499): **Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.paths**
>   12-01 01:33:14.658: E/AndroidRuntime(20499):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
>   12-01 01:33:14.658: E/AndroidRuntime(20499):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
>   12-01 01:33:14.658: E/AndroidRuntime(20499):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
>   12-01 01:33:14.658: E/AndroidRuntime(20499):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
>   12-01 01:33:14.658: E/AndroidRuntime(20499):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:643)
>   12-01 01:33:14.658: E/AndroidRuntime(20499):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView

But it looks like there's no such class of android.view.paths, as in a Google search returns no such class, with the nearest being android.graphics.Path. I have no explicit direct reference of that class in my code.

Anyone has experience in creating a custom Android Dialog for Unity? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it's here what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115758/how-to-display-alert-dialog-in-android

Comment: @linabell Thanks for quick response, but this is pretty much what I've done in the jar. My question is really about getting it to work with Unity. As I wrote, I know how to do it inside a pure Android app.