# Handle webview when offline

Tags: android, webview, popup, offline

I just started creating an android app with a WebView.

I have loaded urls successfully, but I would like to display cached pages & a popup dialog that says, "No Internet Connection" when the user does not have an internet connection.

Please help me with this code.

Comment: Can you open and see the webpage when you are offline? In webview also you are just going to load the webpage, then how it become possible?

Answer (score 0):

Breaking this down, you need to different things:

- Detecting if the user has an internet connection
- Displaying a pop up dialog

Here are two helpful posts that describe the above tasks:

- [Detect whether there is an Internet connection available on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238921/detect-whether-there-is-an-internet-connection-available-on-android)
- [How do I display an alert dialog on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115758/how-to-display-alert-dialog-in-android)

Hope this helps, good luck :-)

Comment: Hi Alex, 
Thx for the link. I made the changes.
the problem is when i disconnect data enabled in moblie networking, i can see "Webpage not available" which is not good.
I dont want to show this kind of page to my users, if internet connections not available i want to show some page or popup alert to the users like "Check the internet connection"

how it is possible  ?