# How can i check internet connection on splash screen and show exit and continue dialog box.

Tags: android, splash-screen

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splach);

        splash();
    }
    public void splash() {
        Thread Splash_Timer = new Thread() {
            public void run(){
                try{
                    int Splash_Timer = 0;
                    while(Splash_Timer < 10000){
                        sleep(100);
                        Splash_Timer = Splash_Timer +100;
                    }
                    startActivity(new Intent("Main"));
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally{
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };
        Splash_Timer.start();
    }
```

This is my Splash Screen. It's working. I need to know how to check mobile and wifi internet connection on splash screen.
The dialog box contain Exit and Continue button.
Exit for Close App and Continue for ignore can't connect to internet on mobile.

Comment: Refer to this for connection http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238921/detect-whether-there-is-an-internet-connection-available-on-android and this for alert dialog http://stackoverflow.com/a/2115770/2146871

Comment: Thanks @JuliusSkripkauskas