# Quit confirmation screen for android game with unity

Tags: java, c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making my own android game with unity, I want to make quit confirmation screen just like this one:

[image]

How is it possible to make it using c#?

Comment: You have to use an alert dialog. See [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/09/how-to-show-alert-dialog-in-android/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I display an alert dialog on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115758/how-do-i-display-an-alert-dialog-on-android)

Comment: The type or namespace name `AlertDialog' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: is this a question ?

Comment: Yeah, what's the problem, it doesn't know what's AlertDialog

Comment: You could built it with the unity ui system and just call Application.Quit() when user presses the quit button. (Unless you want that native android look.)

Answer (score 0):

You can access to java.lang.Class and the java.lang.Object like this.

```
AndroidJavaClass unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass ("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
AndroidJavaObject activity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<  AndroidJavaObject >  ("currentActivity");
```

from this you should be able to set GUI components, buttons, and click listeners to imitate an alert dialog

See [this post](http://chikkooos.blogspot.ca/2015/02/accessing-android-or-java-classes-from.html) for further understanding

Comment: I copied the code, still the same problem https://gyazo.com/3d9a782501ceaeebf5b09ba894713f72

Comment: I guess it could means you're missing a reference dont you ?

"if you want to say create a custom dialog you can create a jar library  which has the required code and access the classes in the jar by using the same technique. "

Have you referenced a jar with the code needed ?

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm using visual studio that came with unity

Comment: You have to make a jar with the AlertDialog java code in it, add the jar as a reference to your project, and then you'll be able to manipulate it.

What is a [JAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_(file_format)) ?

Answer (score 0):

I made a small example for you

1. attach the following script on a gameobject (the canvas for example)
2. add to the root of your normal ui (a panel for example) a
   CanvasGroup component
3. add to the root of your quit confirmation ui (a panel for example) a
   CanvasGroup component
4. Link the two canvas group to the gameobject where you put the script
5. For each button (Quit, Confirm yes, Confirm No) add in the Inspector
   a onclick event to the script corresponding method
6. That is all i think (I tried to comment a bit the code for
   reference), [Reference](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/862941/how-do-i-create-an-exit-confirmation-pop-up-when-i.html)

   ```
   public class QuitHandler : MonoBehaviour { 

    public CanvasGroup uiCanvasGroup;
    public CanvasGroup confirmQuitCanvasGroup;

    // Use this for initialization
    private void Awake()
    {
        //disable the quit confirmation panel
        DoConfirmQuitNo();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called if clicked on No (confirmation)
    /// </summary>
    public void DoConfirmQuitNo()
    {
        Debug.Log("Back to the game");

        //enable the normal ui
        uiCanvasGroup.alpha = 1;
        uiCanvasGroup.interactable = true;
        uiCanvasGroup.blocksRaycasts = true;

        //disable the confirmation quit ui
        confirmQuitCanvasGroup.alpha = 0;
        confirmQuitCanvasGroup.interactable = false;
        confirmQuitCanvasGroup.blocksRaycasts = false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called if clicked on Yes (confirmation)
    /// </summary>
    public void DoConfirmQuitYes()
    {
        Debug.Log("Ok bye bye");
        Application.Quit();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called if clicked on Quit
    /// </summary>
    public void DoQuit()
    {
        Debug.Log("Check form quit confirmation");

        //reduce the visibility of normal UI, and disable all interraction
        uiCanvasGroup.alpha = 0.5f;
        uiCanvasGroup.interactable = false;
        uiCanvasGroup.blocksRaycasts = false;

        //enable interraction with confirmation gui and make visible
        confirmQuitCanvasGroup.alpha = 1;
        confirmQuitCanvasGroup.interactable = true;
        confirmQuitCanvasGroup.blocksRaycasts = true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called if clicked on new game (example)
    /// </summary>
    public void DoNewGame()
    {
        Debug.Log("Launch a new game");
    }
   ```