# How do i bind action to a dialog "OK" button in Codename

Tags: java, android, codenameone

This is my code to create the default dialog in Codename one.
When the user clicks ok it must proceed/call a function and when they cancel the dialog should just close.

```
Dialog.show("Confirm", "Do you want to proceed?", "OK", "Cancel");
```

Comment: use Alert Dialog Box

Comment: The solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2115770/2679651). You're welcome.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I display an alert dialog on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115758/how-do-i-display-an-alert-dialog-on-android)

Comment: That's a question for [Codename One](https://www.codenameone.com/) which runs on iOS as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is pretty simple:

```
if (Dialog.show("Confirm", "Do you want to proceed?", "OK", "Cancel")) {
    //Ok action goes here
}
```

If you want to handle `cancel`, just add the else part.