# how i can use AlertDialog in tablayout?

Tags: java, android

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
```

the code above is let us use tablayout. however, it doesn't support AlertDailog.
so my Q: is there a compile that allow me to use AlertDailog in tablayout or at least i can use multiply complie in gradle app.
please i need help.

Comment: Yes You can
[just search how to use AlertDialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115758/how-do-i-display-an-alert-dialog-on-android)

Comment: i understand how to use the ALERTDIALOG but the problem is this dialog is not found in com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0. so i need to change it to com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1

Comment: but the tablayout will not work.