# How to show dialog and change activity if collision detect

Tags: java, android

How do I show dialog here? And end the game and go back to main activity after clicking ok from the dialog?

I am using Android Studio 2.2 on Ubuntu 16.04.

```
for (int i = 0; i < enemyCount; i++) {
    broccolis[i].update(player.getSpeed());

    if (Rect.intersects(player.getDetectCollision(), broccolis[i].getDetectCollision())){
        //need to show dialog and change activity here...
    }
}
```

I'm new to Android programming and Java so please keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

For a dialog you can use one of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115758/how-do-i-display-an-alert-dialog-on-android) answers. I think there are a lot of good examples.

To start an activity you can do it like this:

```
    Intent var = new Intent(this, yourActivity.class);
    startActivity(var);
```