# Activate Phone call on ItemClick

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-phone-call

In my app I am trying to activate phonecall on a Item click for a list item click. But this code is not working at all. After running this code whenever I click on phone call the app is crashing . I have attached my crash report here. As I am very new in android developing. I am not sure how to get rid of thi serror.

My code is-

```
public class AlertDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

private ListView listView1;
private ListView listView2;
private Button cancelButton1;
private Button cancelButton2;
private String[] companyName;
private String[] actionName;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
protected FragmentActivity mActivity;

public AlertDialogFragment(){
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setCancelable(true);
    setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.DialogStyle);


}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_alertlist_contact, container, false);

    //Set Title Dialog
    getDialog().setTitle("Contact");

    //Button,ListView1 Initialization
    listView1=(ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    cancelButton1=(Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.cancel_button1);

    // Defined Array values to show in ListView
    companyName = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.company_name);

    //Create and set Adepter TO ListView1
    adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.first_alertlist_textstyle,android.R.id.text1,companyName);
    listView1.setAdapter(adapter);

    cancelButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dismiss();
        }
    });

    listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            // ListView Clicked item index
            int itemPosition = position;

            if(itemPosition == 0)
            {
                dismiss();
                showDialog2();
            }

            if(itemPosition == 1)
            {
                dismiss();
                showDialog2();
            }
            if(itemPosition == 2)
            {
                dismiss();
                showDialog2();
            }
          .....
        }

    });
    return rootView;
}

private void showDialog2(){

    final AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getActivity(), R.style.DialogStyle);
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.second_alertlist_contact, null);
    dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

    listView2 = (ListView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.listView2);
    cancelButton2=(Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.cancel_button2);


    // Defined Array values to show in ListView
    actionName = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.contact_way);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(),
            R.layout.first_alertlist_textstyle, android.R.id.text1, actionName);

    listView2.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView2.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

            // ListView Clicked item index
            int itemPosition = position;

            if(itemPosition == 0)
            {

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

                builder.setTitle("+1234667");
                //builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to log out?");

                builder.setPositiveButton("Call", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // close the dialog, go to login page

                        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:1234567"));
                        startActivity(callIntent);
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // Do nothing
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();

            }
            if(itemPosition == 1)
            {
                dismiss();
                System.out.println("Hello");;
            }
            if(itemPosition == 2)
            {
                dismiss();
                System.out.println("Hello");;
            }
            if(itemPosition == 3)
            {
                dismiss();
                System.out.println("Hello");;
            }
        }

    });

    dialogBuilder.show();
}
```

}

```
 07-10 15:40:49.134 12970-12970/com.testgrid E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
 07-10 15:40:49.134 12970-12970/com.testgrid E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
  07-10 15:40:49.134 12970-12970/com.testgrid E/MessageQueue-JNI: 
  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
  'android.content.res.Resources$Theme android.content.Context.getTheme()' on a null object reference
                                                                at 
 android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.resolveDialogTheme(AlertDialog.java:113)
                                                                at 
 android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog$Builder.<init>(AlertDialog.java:291)
                                                                at 
 com.testgrid.AlertDialogFragment$3.onItemClick(AlertDialogFragment.java:155)
                                                                at 
android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:310)
```

Comment: Put dialog.dismiss(); after startactivity....,let me know if it work?

Comment: @ElmiraFrhn no it is not working. I have tried in an alternative way but then it is showing Fragment is not attached to Activity

Comment: Do you see dialog at all?

Comment: No. not at all. my code is crashing

Answer (score 1):

You need some permissions forr making calls, put this in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

maybe this tutorial helps https://www.mkyong.com/android/how-to-make-a-phone-call-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to make dialog and call button :
Put context  youractivityname.this or if you are in a fragment getActivity().

```
   AlertDialog.Builder builder;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, android.R.style.Theme_Material_Dialog_Alert);
} else {
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
}
builder.setTitle("Title")
.setMessage("some message")
.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
        // call specific number
    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:1234567"));
                startActivity(callIntent);

    }
 })
.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
        // do anything
    }
 })
.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
.show();
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115758/how-do-i-display-an-alert-dialog-on-android)

Comment: @Elmita what can I use insted of context inside fragment

Comment: put getActivity()

Comment: 07-10 16:04:23.891 3674-3674/com.testgrid E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
07-10 16:04:23.891 3674-3674/com.testgrid E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
07-10 16:04:23.891 3674-3674/com.testgrid E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: Please post all your fragment code ,something is null there! 
Did you put permission in manifest?
I guess your context is null.