# Show firebase push notification in console.log or alert?

Tags: firebase, cordova, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Can we show push notification payload in console.log or alert rather than the normal push notificaiton. In cordova based application?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can handle firebase push notification very easily, just follow the below code snippet and you can understand how to handle firebase Notification payload:

In **MyFirebaseMessagingService:**

```
 @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            handleNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Data Payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());
        }
    }

private void handleNotification(String message) {
        if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
            // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message
            Log.d(TAG, "Notification message: " + message); // It will show notification payload(message) in console log.
        }else{
            // If the app is in background, firebase itself handles the notification
        }
    }
```

For more information or how Firebase Notification works just follow this [link](https://github.com/HypnoticLemon/Push-Notification)

Comment: if you want to show payload in alert just use alert dialog in android : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115758/how-do-i-display-an-alert-dialog-on-android

Comment: // Handle incoming messages. Called when:
// - a message is received while the app has focus
// - the user clicks on an app notification created by a service worker
//   `messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler` handler.
messaging.onMessage(function(payload) {
  console.log('Message received. ', payload);
  // ...
});

Answer (score 0):

if you are using **phonegap-push-plugin** then in the 'notification' event listener you can console.log() the data.

```
 push.on('notification', function(data) {
   console.log(data);
  });
```