# how to fix Nullpointerexception in setOnclicklistener

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

After adding the code from call.eneque I get the error from the title it says a Nullpointerexception on my clickListener, but everything is initialized or do I overlook something? I looked for hours now tried different tutorials and fixes but can not find anything.

Here is my code:

```
public void openDialog(){
        AlertDialog.Builder formBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(FriendListActivity.this);
        View formView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.contact_add_form,null);
        final AlertDialog dialog = formBuilder.create();
        final EditText nameText = dialog.findViewById(R.id.nameInput);
        formBuilder.setView(formView);
         dialog.show();


        // Buttons

        sButton = dialog.findViewById(R.id.saveButton);
        sButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                PalaverService friendsAddService = PalaverApiClient.getInstance();
                final String FriendName = nameText.getText().toString();
                Call<ApiResponse> call = friendsAddService.addFriend("", "", FriendName);
                call.enqueue(new Callback<ApiResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<ApiResponse> call, Response<ApiResponse> response) {
                        ApiResponse responseSuccess = response.body();

                        if(responseSuccess.getMessageType().equals(1)){
                            friendListAdapter.add(FriendName);
                        }
                        dialog.hide();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<ApiResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                    }
                });



            }
        });

        abbrechen = dialog.findViewById(R.id.abbrechen);
        abbrechen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.hide();
            }
        });



    }
```

This is my error:

```
  Process: de.paluno.se.palaver, PID: 16209
        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
```

The error is coming on my setOnclickListener. Hopefully someone can give me an pointer.

Comment: Can you confirm if your dialog layout **R.layout.contact_add_form** has the ids **R.id.saveButton** and **R.id.abbrechen**?

Answer (score 1):

you have to get your button widget from the `formView`

```
    View formView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.contact_add_form,null);
    final EditText nameText = formView.findViewById(R.id.nameInput);
    sButton = formView.findViewById(R.id.saveButton);
```

Comment: Hi, I did that the buttons now don't give me an error but now my dialog is not shown only the display is getting a bit darker but I still see the old View

Comment: Check this question it will help you because you are building your dialog wrongly ... and also please consider my answer if it helped you to fix your first problem

Comment: which question do you mean? Yes your question did help me with my first problem. What do you mean I am building my dialog wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115758/how-do-i-display-an-alert-dialog-on-android