# How create a user interfaces Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I want to create 4 buttons in the MaintActivity, which when pressing must do operations with RadioButton, checkbok control, spinner control and listview control.

**Question:**

Should I create 4 interfaces (activities) to carry out this type of operations?

Is there another way to do it? How can I do it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could actually just use an alert dialog to show the controls. But you are correct, you can have separate activities as well and you can open them using intent.

`btn.setOnClickListener { startActivity(Intent(this, SpinnerActivity::class.java)) }`

Check out [how to display alertdialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115758/how-do-i-display-an-alert-dialog-on-android).