# How to create a Lottie Alert Dialog in Java

Tags: java, android, lottie

I've tried searching for the Java tutorial regarding creating my `LottieAlertDialog`, but I can't find any. Everywhere it's in Kotlin, but I need the Java code as my project is in Java.

I've tried creating my `LottieAlertDialog` in this way:

```
LottieAlertDialog.Builder alert=new LottieAlertDialog.Builder(context,DialogTypes.TYPE_CUSTOM,
                        "social.json") //Here social.json is inside assets folder
                        .setTitle("Social")
                        .setDescription("social");
                alert.build();
```

But the dialogbox doesn't show, when I run the app. To check whether my alert dialogbox was being created or not I tried testing it by printing the description set in the dialog in a `Toast`:

```
Toast.makeText(context,alert.getDescription(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

The toast works and its showing `"social"`! That means the dialog is being created. But unfortunately it doesn't show in my app. What do I do? I've implemented all the dependencies as shown in the below link:

[lottiealertdialog](https://github.com/mayuce/LottieAlertDialog)

Comment: from the link you've posted they clearly do `.build()` and then `alertDialog.show()`. are you saying there's no show option available ?

Comment: There's no `show()` in java. But there is `.build()`

Comment: cool, just making sure, i can't try this myself so was just wondering :)

Comment: Are you using this library: https://github.com/mayuce/LottieAlertDialog ?

Comment: Yes, I have followed each and every step. But unfortunately his project is in kotlin, and mine in java. Hence the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after much hankering, I finally came to the solution. It's

```
alert.build().show();
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing is not related to Kotlin or Java as such, you need to show the dialog once you have built it. So far your code is correct. You just need to show it further like this

```java
LottieAlertDialog.Builder alert = new LottieAlertDialog.Builder(context, DialogTypes.TYPE_CUSTOM,
                "social.json")
                .setTitle("Social")
                .setDescription("Social")
                .build()
                .show();
```

Comment: There is no such method called `show()` in java

Comment: @Abhishek That seems highly unlikely since Kotlin code is interoperable with Java, could you please tell then after building, what all methods does IDE show you?

Comment: `build(), setTitle(), getDescription(), copy()` and many more. But nothing called `show()`

Comment: @Abhishek I just checked source code for the `LotteAlertDialog`, it just extends the normal `AlertDialog` class, could you try just building a normal dialog and checking if for that the `show()` method is there. Here is some [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115758/how-do-i-display-an-alert-dialog-on-android)

Comment: Yes `AlertDialog` has `show()`, but not `LotteAlertDialog`.

Comment: @Abhishek, I just checked for myself, the method is there, I am updating the code. You can try to copy paste it directly and it should work.

Comment: It's ok, I've found the solution

Comment: @Abhishek Yes, that is what it was it. We were finishing the command of `build()` as we added semicolon after it.