# How to create a window with the message "Are you sure you want to delete this?"

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I'm doing an app in Kotlin where I want to be able to delete things from Realtime Firebase, but before doing that ask the user if he/she/they is sure of that. The idea is having a little window asking that and then having 2 buttons, one that cancels and another that deletes the information from Firebase. Can you help me?

Comment: You can use an alert dialog to do this. Checkout this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115758/how-do-i-display-an-alert-dialog-on-android).

Comment: Hey Mariana, what have you tried so far in code for that?

Comment: Hi @AlexMamo! I'm currently trying to do a AlertDialog, it apperently will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is an [AlertDialog](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs) or a [MaterialAlertDialogBuilder](https://material.io/components/dialogs/android#using-dialogs)

Have included a simple solution for your reference:

```
val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_delete)
                    .setTitle("Delete")
                    .setMessage("Proceed and Delete")
                    .setPositiveButton("Delete"){ dialog, which ->
                        //Call your Firebase Code/function to delete inside here
                    }.setNegativeButton("Cancel"){dialog, which ->

                       //You don't need this in your case and can skip it
                    }.create()
                    .show()
```

Cheers,